# How to search a telerik radgrid wpf with large data

Tags: wpf, prism, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a telerik RadGRid wpf it has the columns 
studentID, Marks, Status usually it contains large data.
A dropdownlist is added beside the telerik grid it contains all the student
Ids, when user selects a particular studentId and click the button Go(which
is added under the dropdownlist) the grid should show only the rows with
the same studentId. How to do this we are following MVVM Prism Pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to handle this is to add a filter.  See [Telerik's Documentation on filtering a DataGridView](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/raddatafilter-how-to-filter-radgridview.html).

Comment: present we are using this feature,but they the dropdownlist way How to proceed on this ?

Comment: @user1016740 See: http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/raddatafilter-how-to-create-custom-filter-editors.html

Comment: here telerik grid and dropdown search are both user controls and they 
are added in View.so wiht given examples didn't find way to do this ?
is there any other way for this rek?

Answer (score 0):

I think filtering should be done first at the database level. As the client chooses a filter criteria only the relevant data will be queried and will be pulled down to the client. And if you need filtering in the client side again. You could use a WPF collection view source which would help you to filter down data. Apart from this telerik Radgrid provides its own filtering for the data coloumns.